# How to insert vim's current working directory into a command

Tags: vim

I'm trying to create a shortcut that automatically connects a repl scoped to my current working directory in vim.

For those who are interested, the use case is connecting to `'figwheel-sidecar.repl-api` using Tim Pope's `fireplace.vim` plugin.

Here's my best attempt:

```
nnoremap <leader>cfr :Connect nrepl://localhost:7002 getcwd()<cr>
```

Most of this is straightforward, but the `getcwd()` segment of the current command doesn't work. What can I use in its place so that whenever I hit `<leader>cfr` it is expanded to this:

```
:Connect nrepl://localhost:7002 path/to/working/directory<cr>
```

n.b. Even better would be to also find a command that is dynamically expanded to the project root (the closest directory with a `.git` file).

Answer (score 0):

Build your command with `:execute`, then the function will be called
properly:

```
nnoremap <leader>cfr :exe 'Connect nrepl://localhost:7002' getcwd()<cr>
```

To expand to your git root, you could use:

```
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
```

So just call that with `system()` instead of `getcwd()`. It might be
a good idea to wrap a `trim()` around to remove the newline:

```
nnoremap <leader>cfr :Connect nrepl://localhost:7002
                            \ trim(system('git rev-parse --show-toplevel'))<cr>
```

Note that  `trim()` is Vim  8+. If for  some reason you're  using an
older version, use `systemlist()` instead:

```
systemlist('git rev-parse --show-toplevel')[0]
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me I'm afraid. I also tried a couple of variations:
`nnoremap <leader>cfr :execute 'Connect' 'nrepl://localhost:7002' fnameescape(getcwd())<cr>` and `nnoremap <leader>cfr :execute 'Connect nrepl://localhost:7002' fnameescape(getcwd())<cr>`.

Comment: What's the error you're getting? I don't know about the `:Connect` command. Don't you need quotes or something?

Comment: The usual long stream of text that it returns when it hasn't found the repl. Going through the step by step wizard works correctly, but I'm trying to define a shortcut to do it in one go. I used quotes in both examples, so I'm not sure what you mean by that?

Comment: So if you type the command and the cwd manually it works, but the `:exe ...` I gave in the answer does not. Correct?

Comment: The quotes you used are for building the command. They are not in the command itself. Tell me, how do you have to type it manually for it to work properly?

Comment: Manually typing the path works, i.e. `:exe 'Connect nrepl://localhost:7002 ~/path/to/clojure-project'

Comment: That's exactly what the command I gave in the answer will produce. Are you sure the problem isn't somewhere else?

Comment: I can't think of anything that could be interfering with vimscript, so I'm confident the command isn't being read correctly.

Comment: The git variation is also unsuccessful.

Comment: @adc17 Are you sure that typing the path in the command works? I mean, i.e.: what does `git rev-parse ...` returns? If you type then `:Connect urepl[...] {result-of-git}` does it really work?

Comment: Interesting. This fails:
`:Connect nrepl://localhost:7002 ~/path/to/repo`
but this succeeds:
`:exe 'Connect nrepl://localhost:7002 ~/path/to/repo'`

Comment: Hard-coding the path I want as a mapping also fails: 
`nnoremap <leader>cfr :exe 'Connect nrepl://localhost:7002 ~/path/to/repo'<cr>`

Comment: @adc17 I'm sorry, but some of your comments contradicts themselves, which makes it very confusing to me to follow the line of thought. I can only see that we are diverging from the original question, which I already answered. Two questions, actually.

Comment: please let me know where I've contradicted myself—I'm just trying to give you info on what is and isn't working.

Comment: Successful:
1. `:exe 'Connect nrepl://localhost:7002 ~/path/to/repo'`
Failed:
1. `:Connect nrepl://localhost:7002 ~/path/to/repo`
2. `nnoremap <leader>cfr :exe 'Connect nrepl://localhost:7002 ~/path/to/repo'<cr>`
3. `nnoremap <leader>cfr :exe 'Connect nrepl://localhost:7002' getcwd()<cr>`
4. `nnoremap <leader>cfr :Connect nrepl://localhost:7002 trim(system('git rev-parse --show-toplevel'))<cr>`

That's all the commands so far, with their result.